# Google maps stops the Android Studio application

Tags: android-studio, google-maps-api-3

I am working with google maps, calling the activity from a button, had a problem, the application stops when I try to open the map activity

My manifest

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.alwaysecure">

    <!--
         The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
         Google Maps Android API v2, but you must specify either coarse or fine
         location permissions for the 'MyLocation' functionality.
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION."/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <!--
             The API key for Google Maps-based APIs is defined as a string resource.
             (See the file "res/values/google_maps_api.xml").
             Note that the API key is linked to the encryption key used to sign the APK.
             You need a different API key for each encryption key, including the release key that is used to
             sign the APK for publishing.
             You can define the keys for the debug and release targets in src/debug/ and src/release/.
        -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MapsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_maps"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy"
            android:required="false"/>

    </application>

</manifest>



El activity del mapa:


    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MapsActivity">

        <fragment
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:context=".MapsActivity"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="-100dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="212dp" />




</fragment>
```

The activity that calls the map activity:

```
   package com.example.alwaysecure;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button btn_login, btn_registrar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btn_login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_login);
        btn_registrar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_register);

        btn_login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MapsActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        /*btn_registrar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),RegistrarActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });*/
    }
}
```

The error:

```
07/18 03:04:25: Launching 'app' on Nexus 5 API 24.
$ adb shell am start -n "com.example.alwaysecure/com.example.alwaysecure.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Waiting for process to come online...
Connected to process 27619 on device 'Nexus_5_API_24 [emulator-5554]'.
Capturing and displaying logcat messages from application. This behavior can be disabled in the "Logcat output" section of the "Debugger" settings page.
W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.alwaysecure-2/lib/x86
W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter androidx.vectordrawable.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
D/: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xa9876880, tid 27619
D/: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xa2733000, tid 27642
I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 0
D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xad4850c0: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xad4850c0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xad4835e0)
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xad4850c0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xad4835e0)
I/zzbz: Making Creator dynamically
I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.maps_dynamite:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.maps_dynamite:203113001
    Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.maps_dynamite, version >= 203113001
V/DynamiteModule: Dynamite loader version >= 2, using loadModule2NoCrashUtils
W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: 
W/ResourceType: ResTable_typeSpec entry count inconsistent: given 67, previously 69
    ResTable_typeSpec entry count inconsistent: given 2885, previously 2906
    ResTable_typeSpec entry count inconsistent: given 471, previously 3453
W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/user_de/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/0000001a/n/x86
I/Google Maps Android API: Google Play services client version: 12451000
I/Google Maps Android API: Google Play services package version: 212418022
I/Google Maps Android API: Google Play services maps renderer version(legacy): 203113001
D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.alwaysecure, PID: 27619
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.alwaysecure/com.example.alwaysecure.MapsActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class fragment
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class fragment
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class fragment
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #12: Duplicate id 0xffffffff, tag null, or parent id 0x7f0900d2 with another fragment for com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentLayoutInflaterFactory.onCreateView(FragmentLayoutInflaterFactory.java:116)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:135)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:319)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:298)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:777)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:858)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:414)
        at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2414)
        at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.setContentView(ComponentActivity.java:380)
        at com.example.alwaysecure.MapsActivity.onCreate(MapsActivity.java:28)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6662)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
Process 27619 terminated.
```

The project was already finished, but due to a name change it got damaged and started showing this error, I'm doing it again from scratch but it keeps showing me this same error.